# Is it possible to expand a parameter pack into different member functions?

Tags: c++, templates

Basically what I'm thinking about is:

```
template<typename... Types>
class Foo
{
    void Bar(Types var) {};...
};
```

which when specialized like this:

```
Foo<S1, S2, S3> foo;
```

to expand to:

```
class Foo
{
    void Bar(S1 var){};
    void Bar(S2 var){};
    void Bar(S3 var){};
};
```

Obviously, it does not make sense in some way but I'll be happy to see some thoughts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template<class D, class T>
struct FooHelper {
  void Bar(T var) {
    auto* self=static_cast<D*>(this);
    // here use self instead of this
  };
};
template<typename... Types>
class Foo: FooHelper<Foo,Types>...
{
  template<class D,class T>
  friend struct FooHelper<D,T>;
};
```

this is how you do what you want to do.

We use use the CRTP to give the base class access to everything in `Foo`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nice C++17 way to do that:

```
template<typename T>
struct HelpFoo {
  void Bar(T) {}
};

template<typename... Types>
struct Foo : HelpFoo<Types>...
{
    using HelpFoo<Types>::Bar...;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can let your methods be templated, and use `enable_if` to enable those in the pack list:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class... Ts>
struct foo {
    template<class T, std::enable_if_t<
        std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>, int> = 0>
   void bar(T);

};
```

Comment: Note that this is close, but doesn't overload in the same way.

Comment: @Yakk Agree, especially conversions are disabled because of deduction.